# Для чего нужен хак min-width: 0\0?

Tags: css

В фреймворке `foundaiton` используют данный хак. Для чего он нужен?

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
  @if lightness($color) < 60% {
    // White triangle
    background-image: url('');
  }
  @else {
    // Black triangle
    background-image: url('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, он работает только на некоторых версиях IE (9, 10, 11).

Comment: http://browserbu.gs/css-hacks/media-min-width-0-backslash-0/